# How to change page in mateiral ui table based on search?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Like the title says I need to change the page based on search value. What do I mean by this, let's say that the name  `Test` is on th page 2 of my table, but not on page 1. How do I then change the page automatically?

Here is my TableComponent.js:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Table from "@mui/material/Table";
import TableBody from "@mui/material/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@mui/material/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@mui/material/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@mui/material/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@mui/material/TableRow";
import useFetch from "./custom_hooks/useFetch";
import TableFooter from "@mui/material/TableFooter";
import TablePagination from "@mui/material/TablePagination";
import IconButton from "@mui/material/IconButton";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import { MdKeyboardArrowRight, MdKeyboardArrowLeft } from "react-icons/md";
import styled from "styled-components";

const TableH = styled(TableHead)`
  height: 3.5rem;
`;

const TableB = styled(TableBody)`
  height: 3.375rem;
`;

const RoleButton = styled.button`
  color: #c80539;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1.43;
  letter-spacing: normal;
`;

function TablePaginationActions(props) {
  const { page, onPageChange } = props;

  const handleBackButtonClick = (event) => {
    onPageChange(event, page);
  };

  const handleNextButtonClick = (event) => {
    onPageChange(event, page + 2);
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ flexShrink: 0, ml: 2.5 }}>
      <IconButton
        onClick={handleBackButtonClick}
        disabled={page === 0}
        aria-label="previous page"
      >
        <MdKeyboardArrowLeft color="#707070" />
      </IconButton>
      <IconButton onClick={handleNextButtonClick} aria-label="next page">
        <MdKeyboardArrowRight color="#707070" />
      </IconButton>
    </Box>
  );
}

const TableComponent = ({ url, cellNames, value }) => {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = useState(5);
  const [roles, setRoles] = useState("Admin");
  const { data, error } = useFetch(`${url}${page}`);

  if (!data) {
    return <h1> LOADING...</h1>;
  }

  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

  const handleChangePage = (event, newPage) => {
    setPage(newPage);
  };
  const handleChangeRowsPerPage = (event) => {
    setRowsPerPage(parseInt(event.target.value, 10));
  };

  // currently this is not functional as it is supposed to be, right now when you click on a button it is going to change role for everyone
  const handleRoleChange = () => {
    if (roles === "Admin") {
      setRoles("User");
    } else {
      setRoles("Admin");
    }
  };

  return (
    <TableContainer
      style={{
        height: 385,
        border: "1px solid #e2e2e3",
        borderRadius: 5,
      }}
      data-testid="table-container"
    >
      <Table stickyHeader>
        <TableH>
          <TableRow>
            {cellNames.map((names, index) => {
              return (
                <TableCell
                  style={{
                    fontWeight: "bold",
                    fontSize: 14,
                    paddingRight: names.paddingRight,
                    paddingLeft: names.paddingLeft,
                  }}
                  align={names.align}
                  key={index}
                >
                  {names.name}
                </TableCell>
              );
            })}
          </TableRow>
        </TableH>
        <TableB>
          {data.data
            .filter((val) => {
              const notFound = !val.name
                .toLowerCase()
                .includes(value.toLowerCase());
              if (value === "") {
                return val;
              } else if (val.name.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())) {
                return val;
              } else if (notFound) {
                // WHAT TO DO HERE ????
              }
            })
            .slice(0, rowsPerPage)
            .map((apiData, index) => {
              return (
                <TableRow key={index}>
                  <TableCell align="left" style={{ paddingLeft: 40 }}>
                    {apiData.name}
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="left">{apiData.email}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="left">{apiData.status}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="left">{roles}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right" style={{ paddingRight: 40 }}>
                    <RoleButton onClick={handleRoleChange}>
                      {roles === "Admin" ? "Set as User" : "Set as Admin"}
                    </RoleButton>
                  </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              );
            })}
        </TableB>
        <TableFooter>
          <TableRow>
            <TablePagination
              rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10]}
              colSpan={6}
              style={{
                borderBottom: "none",
                height: 50,
                color: "#707070",
              }}
              count={data.meta.pagination.total}
              rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
              page={page - 1}
              SelectProps={{
                inputProps: {
                  "aria-label": "rows per page",
                },
                native: true,
              }}
              onPageChange={handleChangePage}
              onRowsPerPageChange={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
              ActionsComponent={TablePaginationActions}
            />
          </TableRow>
        </TableFooter>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
};

export default TableComponent;
```

If anyone know how to do this, I would greatly appreciate that. As I only recently started using Material UI, this seems complicated for me. I assume that somehow I need to change page based on condition that the value is not found on current page, but how do I implement that?

Comment: Teoretically, if you filter the table you should see only records that match with filter. Anyway, you should do something like: search the index of record in your collection and then desume in which page this record is (you know max record per page so the calculation is easy) and then switch to the page found.

Comment: How do I switch to the page, that is the issue I have

Comment: calling handleChangePage programmatically?

Comment: handleChangePage requires the argument for a new page, how do I then pass the argument of a new page, to be precise what is the new page in this case?

Comment: I wrote in my first comment: you should find the index of element searched in collection. Found this index the page to pass to `handleChangePage` is easy (you know the index, you know how many elements you have per page so....)

Comment: I cannot find the index of the element that is not on the first page, only for those that are on the first page